# I want to sort the List of RealmSwift

Tags: swift, realm

I am using RealmSwift.
Data is a one-to-many relationship.

I'm having trouble because I don't know how to sort the list in RealmSwift.

I want to sort the tasks linked to the TaskList.

Thank you.

```
class TaskList: Object, Identifiable {
    @objc dynamic var id = NSUUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()

    var tasks: List<Task> = List<Task>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    } }

class Task: Object, Identifiable {
    @objc dynamic var id = NSUUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()

    private let lists = LinkingObjects(fromType: TaskList.self, property: "tasks")
    var list: TaskList { return list.first! }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    } }
```

Comment: Lists maintain their order so if you want the objects in this `var tasks: List<Task> = List<Task>()` in the order they were added, you don't need to do anything. Do you want to sort them by some other property? If so, which one? And do you want Realm to sort them or sort them in code (code is fine for small lists). Also, do you want to maintain that order? In other words, if a new Task is added do you want it to automatically sort or will you sort it later? It's a good idea to include complete information when asking questions so we can provide a more complete and accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your tasks stored in an ordered fashion you'll have to manually do an ordered insert.

```
extension List {
    func insert<V: Comparable>(_ object: Element, orderedBy keyPath: KeyPath<Element, V>) {
        var index = 0
        for i in 0..<count {
            if self[i][keyPath: keyPath] >= object[keyPath: keyPath] {
                break
            }
            index = i + 1
        }
        insert(object, at: index)
    }
}

let list = TaskList()

let tasks = [
    Task(title: "J"),
    Task(title: "Z"),
    Task(title: "T"),
    Task(title: "J"),
    Task(title: "Z"),
]

tasks.forEach {
    list.tasks.insert($0, orderedBy: \.title)
}
```

However, I find it much easier to keep `Lists` unsorted and retrieve sorted `Results` whenever I need to display the data. To sort by a single property just call `sorted(byKeyPath:)`:

```
let sortedTasks = taskList.tasks.sorted(byKeyPath: "title")
```

To sort by multiple fields call `sorted(by:)`:

```
let sortedTasks = taskList.tasks.sorted(by: [
    SortDescriptor(keyPath: "title"),
    SortDescriptor(keyPath: "createdAt")
])
```

Alternatively, you can add a sorted property to your Model:

```
class TaskList: Object, Identifiable {
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = Date()

    var tasks = List<Task>()

    lazy var sortedTasks: Results<Task> = tasks.sorted(byKeyPath: "title")

    override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["sortedTasks"]
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a `LinkingObjects` itself to be sorted, but you can call `LinkingObjects.sorted(byKeyPath:)`, which returns a `Results` instance containing all elements of the `LinkingObjects`, just sorted.

```
class Task: Object, Identifiable {
    @objc dynamic var id = NSUUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()

    private let lists = LinkingObjects(fromType: TaskList.self, property: "tasks")
    lazy var sortedLists = lists.sorted(byKeyPath: "createdAt")
    var list: TaskList { return list.first! }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a one line answer. If you know which TaskList object you want to get the tasks for, and you want them ordered by say, creation date. This will do it

```
let taskResults = realm.objects(Task.self)
                       .filter("ANY lists == %@", taskList)
                       .sorted(byKeyPath: "createdAt")
```